# Como retornar mais de uma propriedade com JSON?

Tags: php, json, return

Gostaria de saber como eu retorno mais de uma propriedade no PHP.
Abaixo tem o código onde eu retorno o nome do usuário e queria retornar, além disso, a matrícula dele. Tentei fazer da mesma forma só acrescentando a 'matricula', porém não deu certo.

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
session_start();
if($_SESSION['logado']) {
    $nome = $_SESSION['nome'];
    //$matricula = $_SESSION['matricula'];
} 
echo json_encode(array('nomeUsuario' => $nome));
//'matricula' => $matricula));
?>
```

Comment: de que forma você tentou? Utilizando `echo json_encode(array('nomeUsuario' => $nome, 'matricula' => $matricula));` deveria funcionar.

Comment: isso, Oeslei. Tentei dessa forma.

Comment: Talvez a sua variável `$_SESSION['matricula']` esteja vazia? Qual a resposta que o navegador recebe (veja diretamente no console do navegador)?

Comment: No console é retornado o nome do usuário direitinho, mas a matrícula aparece null.

Comment: Mas aparece o campo matrícula certo? Ter o valor `null` não significa que não está funcionando. Como eu disse no outro comentário, sua variável `$_SESSION['matricula']` deve estar vazia.

Comment: O campo matricula aparece, mas no meu banco de dados o campo de matrícula não está vazio...

Comment: Coloque o seu comando `echo` desta forma: `echo json_encode($_SESSION);` e analize todos os campos da sua session. Mesmo que a matrícula esteja correta no banco, talvez seu script para setar a session possua algum erro.

Comment: Todos os campos apareceram, menos o da matrícula..

Comment: dá um `print_r` para ver se a matrícula está na `$_SESSION`

Comment: A matrícula não apareceu no `print_r`,

Comment: se matrícula é inexistente na SESSION, então o buraco é mais embaixo.. Procure no script que cria a SESSION, pois lá é que deve estar o problema..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como me foi sugerido, dei uma olhada no script onde inicializo a sessão e percebi que estava faltando uma linha de código que delegasse a matrícula.

```
if($array['login'] == $login){                
            if($array['password'] == $senha){
                $_SESSION['logado'] = true;
                $_SESSION['nome'] = $array['nome'];
                $_SESSION['login'] = $array['login'];
                $_SESSION['level'] = $array['level'];
                $_SESSION['matricula'] = $array['matricula']; //ESSA ERA A LINHA QUE FALTAVA
                ...
                ...
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta adicionar o dado no array, assim

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'nomeUsuario' => $nome,
    'outro_dado' => 'novo dado'
));
```

Comment: Fiz isso, Beraldo. Pode ver lá em cima que está comentado. Porém, não deu certo.